# Django FileField() upload only Excel Files

Tags: python, django

this is my model.py

```
class Data(models.Model):
    """ Model of Data"""
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    document = models.FileField(upload_to="documents/%Y/%m/%d")
    uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.document)
```

forms.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Data


class DataForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Data
        fields = ['document']
```

**Kindly asking, I just want to upload Excel file only, What should I do?**

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
class Meta:
    model = Data
    fields = ['document']
    widgets = {
        'document': forms.widgets.FileInput(attrs={'accept': 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet, application/vnd.ms-excel'})
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for you effort @riNg, this error show AttributeError: module 'django.forms.forms' has no attributes 'widgets'.. and I try this code forms.FileInput(attrs={'accept': ........}  but still error has no attributes FileInput.

Comment: Find the solution to my problem.. before the import is from django.forms import forms should change to from django import forms